# Can I randomly sample from a HashSet efficiently?

Tags: random, rust, hashset

I have a `std::collections::HashSet`, and I want to sample and remove a uniformly random element.

Currently, what I'm doing is randomly sampling an index using `rand.gen_range`, then iterating over the `HashSet` to that index to get the element. Then I remove the selected element. This works, but it's not efficient. Is there an efficient way to do randomly sample an element?

Here's a stripped down version of what my code looks like:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

extern crate rand;
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::Rng;

let mut hash_set = HashSet::new();

// ... Fill up hash_set ...

let index = thread_rng().gen_range(0, hash_set.len());
let element = hash_set.iter().nth(index).unwrap().clone();
hash_set.remove(&element);

// ... Use element ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2023, the [hashbrown](https://crates.io/crates/hashbrown) crate, which implements the Rust Standard Library's HashSet, has introduced the RawTable API, which allows unsafe, lower-level access to the internal state of the HashSet. Using this API, we can directly implement random removal from the HashSet:

```
use hashbrown::HashSet;
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn remove_random<T, R>(set: &mut HashSet<T>, rng: &mut R) -> Option<T>
where
    R: Rng,
    T: Eq + PartialEq + Hash,
{
    if set.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }
    // If load factor is under 25%, shrink to fit.
    // We need a high load factor to ensure that the sampling succeeds in a reasonable time,
    // and the table doesn't rebalance on removals.
    // Insertions can only cause the load factor to reach as low as 50%,
    // so it's safe to shrink at 25%.
    if set.capacity() >= 8 && set.len() < set.capacity() / 4 {
        set.shrink_to_fit();
    }
    let raw_table = set.raw_table_mut();
    let num_buckets = raw_table.buckets();
    // Perform rejection sampling: Pick a random bucket, check if it's full,
    // repeat until a full bucket is found.
    loop {
        let bucket_index = rng.gen_range(0..num_buckets);
        // Safety: bucket_index is less than the number of buckets.
        // Note that we return the first time we modify the table,
        // so raw_table.buckets() never changes.
        // Also, the table has been allocated, because set is a HashSet.
        unsafe {
            if raw_table.is_bucket_full(bucket_index) {
                let bucket = raw_table.bucket(bucket_index);
                let ((element, ()), _insert_slot) = raw_table.remove(bucket);
                return Some(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program requires the "raw" feature of the hashbrown crate to be enabled, with a `Cargo.toml` like the following:

```
[dependencies]
hashbrown = { version = "^0.14.2", features = ["raw"] }
rand = "^0.8.5"
```

Answer (score 7):

The only data structures allowing uniform sampling in constant time are data structures with constant time index access. `HashSet` does not provide indexing, so you can’t generate random samples in constant time.

I suggest to convert your hash set to a `Vec` first, and then sample from the vector. To remove an element, simply move the last element in its place – the order of the elements in the vector is immaterial anyway.

If you want to consume all elements from the set in random order, you can also shuffle the vector once and then iterate over it.

Here is an example implementation for removing a random element from a `Vec` in constant time:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

pub trait RemoveRandom {
    type Item;

    fn remove_random<R: Rng>(&mut self, rng: &mut R) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}

impl<T> RemoveRandom for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn remove_random<R: Rng>(&mut self, rng: &mut R) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.len() == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let index = rng.gen_range(0..self.len());
            Some(self.swap_remove(index))
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d336dcaf242d926ea7c85fb9f566858))

Answer (score 6):

Thinking about Sven Marnach's answer, I want to use a vector, but I also need constant time insertion with duplication. Then I realized that I can maintain both a vector and a set, and ensure that they both have the same elements at all times. This will allow both constant time insertion with deduplication and constant time random removal.

Here's the implementation I ended up with:

```
struct VecSet<T> {
    set: HashSet<T>,
    vec: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> VecSet<T>
where
    T: Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            set: HashSet::new(),
            vec: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, elem: T) {
        assert_eq!(self.set.len(), self.vec.len());
        let was_new = self.set.insert(elem.clone());
        if was_new {
            self.vec.push(elem);
        }
    }
    fn remove_random(&mut self) -> T {
        assert_eq!(self.set.len(), self.vec.len());
        let index = thread_rng().gen_range(0, self.vec.len());
        let elem = self.vec.swap_remove(index);
        let was_present = self.set.remove(&elem);
        assert!(was_present);
        elem
    }
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        assert_eq!(self.set.len(), self.vec.len());
        self.vec.is_empty()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sven's answer suggests converting the `HashSet` to a `Vec`, in order to randomly sample from the `Vec` in O(1) time. This conversion takes O(n) time, which is probably fine if the conversion needs to be done sparingly, but may become unwieldy if conversions need to be done often, e.g., if, between taking random samples,  one wants to intersperse some O(1) removals-by-value  from the `HashSet`, since that would involve converting back and forth between `HashSet` and `Vec`, with each conversion taking O(n) time.

isaacg's solution is to keep both a `HashSet` and a `Vec` and operate on them in tandem. This allows O(1) lookup-by-index, O(1) random removal, and O(1) insertion, but *not* O(1) lookup-by-value or O(1) removal-by-value (because the `Vec` can't do those).

Below, I give a data structure that allows O(1) lookup-by-either-index-or-value, O(1) insertion, and O(1) removal-by-either-index-or-value, at the cost of O(n) more memory:

It is a `HashMap<T, usize>` together with a `Vec<T>`, such that the `Vec` maps indexes (which are `usizes`) to `T`s, while the `HashMap` maps `T`s to `usizes`. The `HashMap` and `Vec` can be thought of as [inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of one another, so that you can go from an index to its value, and from a value back to its index. The insertion and deletion operations are defined so that the indexes are precisely the integers from 0 to size()-1, with no gaps allowed. I call this data structure a [`BijectiveFiniteSequence`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). (Note the `take_random_val` method; it works in O(1) time.)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct BijectiveFiniteSequence<T: Eq + Copy + Hash> { 
    idx_to_val: Vec<T>,
    val_to_idx: HashMap<T, usize>,
}
impl<T: Eq + Copy + Hash> BijectiveFiniteSequence<T> {
    fn new () -> BijectiveFiniteSequence<T> {
        BijectiveFiniteSequence {
            idx_to_val: Vec::new(),
            val_to_idx: HashMap::new()
        }
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        self.idx_to_val.push(val);
        self.val_to_idx.insert(val, self.len()-1);
    }
    fn take_random_val(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let rand_idx: usize = rng.gen_range(0..self.len());
        self.remove_by_idx(rand_idx)
    }
    fn remove_by_idx(&mut self, idx: usize) -> Option<T> {
        match idx < self.len() {
            true => {
                let val = self.idx_to_val[idx];
                let last_idx = self.len() - 1;
                self.idx_to_val.swap(idx, last_idx);
                self.idx_to_val.pop();
                // update hashmap entry after the swap above
                self.val_to_idx.insert(self.idx_to_val[idx], idx);
                self.val_to_idx.remove(&val);
                Some(val)
            },
            false => None
        }
    }
    fn remove_val(&mut self, val: T) -> Option<T> {
        //nearly identical to the implementation of remove_by_idx,above 
        match self.contains(&val) {
            true => {
                let idx: usize = *self.val_to_idx.get(&val).unwrap();
                let last_idx = self.len() - 1;
                self.idx_to_val.swap(idx, last_idx);
                self.idx_to_val.pop();
                // update hashmap entry after the swap above
                self.val_to_idx.insert(self.idx_to_val[idx], idx);
                self.val_to_idx.remove(&val);
                Some(val)
            }
            false => None
        }
    }
    fn get_idx_of(&mut self, val: &T) -> Option<&usize> {
        self.val_to_idx.get(val)
    }
    fn get_val_at(&mut self, idx: usize) -> Option<T> {
        match idx < self.len() {
            true => Some(self.idx_to_val[idx]),
            false => None
        }
    }
    fn contains(&self, val: &T) -> bool {
        self.val_to_idx.contains_key(val)
    }
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.idx_to_val.len()
    }
    // etc. etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks like it fits what I'm looking for much better than the answer I gave. However, the code sample you gave doesn't compile - it gives 13 errors, see this link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02890a0cd7991ec865f72aee0ad08122 Could you update the code?

Comment: You're welcome! I've revised it to a working version just now.

Comment: I believe that `IndexSet` from the [indexmap](https://crates.io/crates/indexmap) crate fulfils the same purpose.

Comment: Vec implements `swap_remove`, doing the same as your `swap(last)` and `pop`. Might be fractionally better (2 copies instead of 3)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.iter) for `HashSet::iter` it returns *"An iterator visiting all elements in arbitrary order."*

Arbitrary is perhaps not exactly uniform randomness, but if it's close enough for your use case, this is O(1) and will return different values each time:

```rust
// Build a set of integers 0 - 99
let mut set = HashSet::new();
for i in 0..100 {
    set.insert(i);
}
// Sample
for _ in 0..10 {
    let n = set.iter().next().unwrap().clone();
    println!("{}", n);
    set.remove(&n);
}
```

Like the author I wanted to remove the value after sampling from the HashSet. Sampling multiple times this way, without altering the HashSet, seems to yield the same result each time.

Comment: Note: this works here cause the hashset is resized. If the hashset is relatively stable, then this won't work.