# Can I pop from a HashSet efficiently?

Tags: rust, hashset

My algorithm needs to iteratively shrink a set by removing an element, and do something with the element removed and with the shrinking set in each iteration. And:

- I need a genuine set with fast lookup, not just a vector containing unique elements.
- The choice of element is arbitrary: the outcome of the algorithm doesn't depend on the order visited. The performance probably varies greatly with that choice, but let's say I want the simplest code and leave it up to the set itself to pick the element it can remove efficiently.
- The elements are cheap to clone (very likely copyable, integers in reality, but let's be explicit about cloning in the examples here).

By the way, the algorithm is [the basic form of the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm). Smarter versions of that algorithm work faster (mostly) because they don't leave the choice of element arbitrary and I'd like to learn how much that effort pays off, compared to optimizing the pop operation.

Python sets have a `pop` member that pretty much does that. In Scala and Go, picking and removing the "first" element of a hash set seems to work fine (where "first" corresponds to the iterator). In Rust, that is something like:

```
// split off an arbitrary element from a (non-empty) set
pub fn pop<T>(set: &mut HashSet<T>) -> T
where
    T: Eq + Clone + std::hash::Hash,
{
    let elt = set.iter().next().cloned().unwrap();
    set.remove(&elt);
    elt
}
```

This seems to be a performance bottleneck compared to other languages, but even to a seemingly naive way do this kind of iteration in Rust: copying the sequence, then popping elements in sequence. I [benchmarked some implementations of a pop-like function on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=78a860fcc8daf780755fb34547056231) but none perform well compared to the naive way.

At first, I thought I saw that removing an element is not expensive, but picking one with `iter().next()` is. But on closer examination, that's not true, at least compared to other languages (*).

Using `retain` understandably doesn't help: it always iterates the whole set. Are there any other alternatives?

(*) On closer examination, `iter().next()` is quite cheap, as far as microbenchmarking can be trusted. [Separate microbenchmarks](https://github.com/ssomers/rust_bench_sets_compared) say that picking an arbitrary element from a set costs (in nanoseconds on my system):

```
| Type of set      | Number of elements in set instance
|                  | 100 | 10,000 | 1,000,000
| Rust HashSet     |   2 |      2 |         2
| Rust BTreeSet    |  11 |     12 |        13
| Go map[]struct{} |  27 |     31 |        94
| Python set       | 125 |    125 |       125
```

Comment: Note that the set I'm using has integers, so I haven't considering memory management - I guess no cloning is necessary at all to move an element out of a set.

Comment: Running benchmarks on the playground is a pretty terrible idea. It's a single shared EC2 instance for everyone. There are a number of reasons that any numbers from there are suspect.

Comment: @Shepmaster that's why it takes a few samples; nevertheless the result is quite consistent in my experience

Comment: "This turns out to be a performance bottleneck compared to the other languages." you didn't prove that. And I really doubt of that too.

Comment: @Stargateur I didn't prove it because I don't know if I'm doing it right, but I do have evidence at https://github.com/ssomers/Bron-Kerbosch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the same advice applies as in [Can I randomly sample from a HashSet efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755017/can-i-randomly-sample-from-a-hashset-efficiently): copy the set as a vector just to iterate over it as shown in the ["sequenced" solution in the benchmark](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=78a860fcc8daf780755fb34547056231):

```
let seq: Vec<u32> = set.iter().cloned().collect();
for elt in seq {
    set.remove(&elt);
```

That means this answer is not applicable if you need to shrink the set (pick an arbitrary element) only once or a few times, or if the set contents cannot be cheaply cloned.

Answer (score 7):

> the set I'm using has integers

Don't use a `HashSet`; A `BTreeSet` has better and more consistent performance.

For `N` = 100000...

**`BTreeSet`**

```
sequenced : 3065.098µs
pop_1     : 2941.876µs
pop_2     : 2927.429µs
```

**`HashSet`**

```
sequenced : 3091.454µs
pop_1     : 172547.080µs
pop_2     : 807182.085µs
```

Comment: Unforunately I'm not seeing better performance replacing HashSet with BTreeSet. In the benchmark above, that only shrinks the set, BTreeSet is a champion indeed. But the complete algorithm is worse off on small sets and orders of magnitude slower on big sets (of a million integers). Profiling suggests it's the intersections done every iteration. Maybe because the sets intersected are typically very asymmetric: HashSet.intersection does the intersection of a small set with a big set quite efficiently.

Comment: WIth a performance-savvier implementation of intersection, BTreeSet  scales as good as HashSet, and better, for some uses at least. Still up to 50% slower for small sets, but faster on huge sets for some algorithms. The intersection implementation is [on github](https://github.com/ssomers/Bron-Kerbosch/blob/master/rust/bron_kerbosch/src/util.rs) and hopefully one day in Rust itself.

Comment: An even more performance-savvy implementation of BTreeSet intersection [has been merged in](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/59186)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified a bit:

```
let elt = set.iter().next().cloned().unwrap();
set.take(&elt).unwrap()
```

If you want to remove all elements from a `HashSet` then you should use the [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.drain) iterator - it is very efficient.

`HashSet` from the Rust standard library is not that fast. Try replacing it with one from the [hashbrown](https://crates.io/crates/hashbrown) crate.

Comment: drain does not allow using the shrinking set, right? It immediately makes the set inaccessible and/or empty.

Comment: *is not that fast* — this is an very misleading statement. The insinuation is that the current implementation of `HashMap` is always *slow*, but the new implementation in hashbrown just happens to be fast*er*. There's even work to replace the standard library implementation with that from hashbrown, which will likely make this point moot eventually.

Comment: I disagree that the proposed code is any simpler. It now has two potential panics as opposed to the original one.

Comment: The proposed code isn't simpler because the code I listed also panics on an empty set, unlike the "better" alternatives on the playground comparison. In proper Rust style, returning an Option, and once you're familiar with it, it is indeed a bit simpler. I wondered if there is a runtime performance difference but [my benchmark on github](https://github.com/ssomers/rust_bench_sets_compared) says they're the same.

Comment: For the use in the question here, the hashbron implementation is better than the standard `HashSet` and than the fnv crate's `FnvHashSet`, but still much less scalable than the standard `BTreeSet`. For the other set usage I evaluated (mainly intersection), they're all equally scalable, hashbrown being the slowest and `FnvHashSet` the fastest.